# Mocha/Chai Test linkTo Function Returning AssertionError

Tags: javascript, function, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to find & correct the Javascript code in **challenge.js** so that it passes the Mocha & Chai tests as specified in **spec.js**.... Nothing I try will get it to pass the tests when I run the command `$ mocha spec.js` in the Terminal.... To provide more information, the resulting error message that is continually returned in the Terminal regardless of any changes I make to **challenge.js** is shown underneath.

**Challenge.js**

```
module.exports.linkTo = function(text, address) {   
  return "<a href='" + text + "'>" + address + "</a>"
};
```

**Spec.js**

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var challenge = require("./challenge.js");

describe("linkTo", function() {
  it("should be defined", function() {
    expect(challenge.linkTo).to.exist;
  });

  it("should return a valid link for Bloc", function() {
    expect(challenge.linkTo("Bloc", "http://www.bloc.io")).to.eql("<a       href='http://www.bloc.io'>Bloc</a>");
  });
});
```

**Error Message as returned in Terminal**

```
linkTo
✓ should be defined 
1) should return a valid link for Bloc


  1 passing (11ms)
  1 failing

  1) linkTo should return a valid link for Bloc:

  AssertionError: expected '<a href=\'Bloc\'>http://www.bloc.io</a>' to deeply equal '<a href=\'http://www.bloc.io\'>Bloc</a>'
  + expected - actual

  +<a href='http://www.bloc.io'>Bloc</a>
  -<a href='Bloc'>http://www.bloc.io</a>

  at Context.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/frontend-javascript-exercises/02-reading-mocha-tests/00-a-tested-function/spec.js:10:63)
  at callFn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:266:21)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:259:7)
  at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:387:10)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:470:12
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:312:14)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:322:7
  at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:257:23)
  at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:289:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Can anyone PLEASE point out the correction(s) needed in **challenge.js** in order for the tests to pass when I run `$ mocha spec.js` in the Terminal???

Thanks in advance
Lex

Answer (score 0):

Replace adress with text and text with address inside function declaration.

```
module.exports.linkTo = function(text, address) {   
  return "<a href='" + address + "'>" + text + "</a>"
};
```

Test output cleary says what was expected

```
+<a href='http://www.bloc.io'>Bloc</a>
-<a href='Bloc'>http://www.bloc.io</a>
```